# issue in merging audio and video file in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
 error is Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
line :-[b_compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:audio_timeRange ofTrack:[[audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:nextClipStartTime error:nil];
```

My code here ------------------------------

```
- (void) getAndPlayAVideoTest
{
    NSString *bundleDirectory = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];

    NSString *videoOutputPath=[bundleDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"abc.mp3"];
    NSString *outputFilePath = [bundleDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"final_video.mp4"];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:outputFilePath])
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager]removeItemAtPath:outputFilePath error:nil];


    NSURL    *outputFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:outputFilePath];
    NSString *filePath = [bundleDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"abc.mov"];
    AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];

    NSURL    *audio_inputFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
    NSURL    *video_inputFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoOutputPath];

    CMTime nextClipStartTime = kCMTimeZero;

    AVURLAsset* videoAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:video_inputFileUrl options:nil];
    CMTimeRange video_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,videoAsset.duration);

    AVMutableCompositionTrack *a_compositionVideoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    [a_compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:video_timeRange ofTrack:[[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:nextClipStartTime error:nil];

    AVURLAsset* audioAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:audio_inputFileUrl options:nil];
    CMTimeRange audio_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, audioAsset.duration);
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *b_compositionAudioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    [b_compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:audio_timeRange ofTrack:[[audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:nextClipStartTime error:nil];

    AVAssetExportSession* _assetExport = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality];
    _assetExport.outputFileType = @"com.apple.quicktime-movie";
    _assetExport.outputURL = outputFileUrl;

    [_assetExport exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:
     ^(void ) {
         if (_assetExport.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted) {

             //Write Code Here to Continue
         }
         else {
             //Write Fail Code here
         }
     }
     ];
//}
}
```

Comment: Have you used the debugger to determine which line it's failing on? There error's pretty obvious - one of your NSArray references is calling an index out of range.

Comment: thanks 

-[b_compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:audio_timeRange ofTrack:[[audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:nextClipStartTime error:nil]; this cannot read array

Comment: Step through the debugger (add a break point) to the line before that and figure out why the audio range is nil. (or length 0)

Comment: sorry i am not understand, what you mean. and please explain .

Comment: In Xcode, in the line numbers margin, click with the mouse. It will create a break-point in the debugger that will let you step through it.

Comment: yes i checked using breakpoint in this line [a_compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:video_timeRange ofTrack:[[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:nextClipStartTime error:nil];
  after crash my code

Comment: so you need to use that and determine why (in the hierarchy if your code) it's causing it to not provide a value.

Comment: I am using the above code but this code not get any value so can you help me my code is right or not? and give me some alternate solution for merging audio & video file
Please if you have any code for merging files please share?

thanks

Comment: please help i am tired

Comment: Sorry Vikrant, but without the context of the debugger I can't help. Sleep on it?

Comment: thanks remus.I done this. using

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"background" ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSString *path1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"00" ofType:@"mov"];
   
    AVURLAsset* audioAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] options:nil];
    AVURLAsset* videoAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path1] options:nil];

Comment: I don't think your pathForResource should be hard coded to 00? I'm not sure though - what do the docs say? (Sorry, using mobile, can't easily look it up).

Answer (score 1):

In that case `[b_compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:audio_timeRange ofTrack:[[audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:nextClipStartTime error:nil];`  this cannot read array.

Because `Sound/Audio` is not present in the particular file.This Error is comes only on those cases,When sound/Audio is not present in the multimedia file.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
AVURLAsset* audioAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:audio_inputFileUrl options:nil];
```